# R read.table with international characters

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, internationalization, text-files

I'm using R 3.0.3 with RStudio on Windows 7. I need to read-in a table from the web with sampling location names:

```
server <- 'http://hydrodata.info/api/'
sites_url <- paste(server, 'sites?var=teplota',sep='')
sites <- read.table(sites_url, sep='\t', header=TRUE)
print(sites$name[25])
```

The output is:

> [1] TÃ¡bor 468 Levels: Å indelovÃ¡ (Obora) Å piÄÃ¡k (Å umava) ...
>   ZlatÃ© Hory

Correct output should be like:

> [1] Tábor  468 Levels: Šindelová (Obora) Špičák (Šumava) ... Zlaté
>   Hory

Why are the international characters á, Š, é ... shown incorrectly? Is this a problem in my R code or on the web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not tell what your default locale is (`Sys.getlocale( "LC_CTYPE" )`). So I can just guess, that

```
sites <- read.table(sites_url, sep='\t', header=TRUE, fileEncoding="utf8")
```

might help.

Comment: > Sys.getlocale( "LC_CTYPE" )
[1] "English_United States.1252"

Comment: The fileEncoding="utf8" in read.table() did the trick. I'm a bit surprised that R didn't recognize the character encoding of the file from the website content-type header ...